# Ionic 3 cordova facebook native plugin gives error when build

Tags: cordova, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic3, cordova-facebook

I got this error when i tried to build my ionic project which has facebook native plugin.

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugApkCopy'.
> Could not find com.android.support:customtabs:27.0.2.


Searched in the following locations:
         file:/Users/MacBook/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/27.0.2/support-annotations-27.0.2.pom
         file:/Users/MacBook/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/27.0.2/support-annotations-27.0.2.jar
         file:/Users/MacBook/Documents/MJMobile/giftin-app/platforms/android/sdk-manager/com/android/support/support-annotations/27.0.2/support-annotations-27.0.2.jar
     Required by:
         project : > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.30.0 > com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.30.0
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.0.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/Users/MacBook/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-core-utils/27.0.2/support-core-utils-27.0.2.pom
         file:/Users/MacBook/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-core-utils/27.0.2/support-core-utils-27.0.2.jar
         file:/Users/MacBook/Documents/MJMobile/giftin-app/platforms/android/sdk-manager/com/android/support/support-core-utils/27.0.2/support-core-utils-27.0.2.jar
     Required by:
         project : > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.30.0 > com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.30.0
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/Users/MacBook/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/27.0.2/support-v4-27.0.2.pom
         file:/Users/MacBook/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/27.0.2/support-v4-27.0.2.jar
         file:/Users/MacBook/Documents/MJMobile/giftin-app/platforms/android/sdk-manager/com/android/support/support-v4/27.0.2/support-v4-27.0.2.jar
```

I read through other solutions for this error at github,SO and many other forums.
I tried all those solutions such as following

1.Replaced mavenCentral() in `build.gradle` file.

2.reinstalling android support repository.

3.re adding android platform into ionic project

But non of this solved the issue. Is there any solution/recommendation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.

Here is What i did.

I was using cordova platform android 6.2.2. First i updated it into android 6.3.0

```
cordova platform update android@6.3.0
```

Then i got the following error

```
Error:Execution failed for task':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
```

Then I removed cordova android platform from my Ionic project. then I added the android 6.3.0

```
cordova platform add android@6.3.0
```

Then my errors fixed and project built successfully.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO @deemantha mediajogger !. It's great if found solution on your own.

Comment: Hey, thanks a million bro, I had a very similar issue!

Comment: Welcome @Gregordy